# Need help setting up IF statement iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

I need help setting up my if statement while users upload a document to my parse database. Right now, the functionality works. But I came across a problem with having 2 objects under a certain criteria, so now when a user goes to upload an image and string, I need to delete the old one and save the new one. Here is my code:

```
let postImage = PFObject(className: "Vaccine")
postImage["expiration"] = expiration.text

let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToPost.image!, 0.2)
let imageFile = PFFile(name: "dogumentImage.jpg", data: imageData!)
postImage["dogumentImage"] = imageFile

let ifActiveQuery = PFQuery(className: "Vaccine")
ifActiveQuery.whereKey("userID", equalTo: self.userID)
ifActiveQuery.whereKey("vaccineType", equalTo: self.vaccineDocument)
ifActiveQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
    if let vaccine = objects {
        for object in vaccine {
            print(object.objectId)
            if object.objectId == nil {
                postImage.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
                    self.expirationField.text = ""
                    self.imageToPost.image = UIImage(named: "addDocument.jpg")
                }
            } else {
                let deleteAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Update Dogument Information?", message: "All old data will be lost.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                deleteAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                    object.deleteInBackground()
                    postImage.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                        self.expirationField.text = ""
                        self.imageToPost.image = UIImage(named: "addDocument.jpg")
                    }
                }))
                deleteAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                        print("Canceled Delete")
                }))
            }
        }
    }
})
```

So before I needed the extra functionality of deleting the old object, my postImage.saveInBackgroundWithBlock method was working perfectly, just not anymore in my query. I've verified that the right values are being passed in for the self.userID and self.vaccineDocument and after debugging, I do have access to the objects I need. I just think some of my wording is wrong in the if object.objectId == nil declaration or something. Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: is object.objectId a String? if yes cast it properly from <AnyObject> to string and try string.isEmpty to check for value.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So it object.objectId is a string so I started my statement like this: 

let objectString = object.objectId! as String
if objectString.isEmpty {

Everything compiled fine but in the case where it was empty my activityIndicator would just spin and spin and wouldn't save to parse. And if it was not empty the same would happen expect in my debugger I got this error:

Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UIAlertController: 0x7ffe1bb56dc0>)

Comment: I just now ran my debugger with a shit ton of breakpoints and basically I am retrieving the location in Parse that I need to, only if the objectString does not exist it just skips over all my code and keeps the activityIndicator going forever. If it does exist, it finds the correct object, has access to all its values but gets stuck in my deleteAlert alert Controller. So i tried it again without the alert controller and it works! It deletes the old object and saves the new object.  I would still like to have that alert controller though. Any new suggestions for either of my problems? Thanks!

Comment: If the objectString doesn't exist it never runs for object in vaccine {, if it does exist it runs the code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for the time being. Instead of using one query I've used 2 different ones that essentially complete my IF statement:

```
let ifActiveQuery = PFQuery(className: "Vaccine")
ifActiveQuery.whereKey("userID", equalTo: self.userID)
ifActiveQuery.whereKey("vaccineType", equalTo: self.vaccineDocument)
ifActiveQuery.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
    objects?.deleteInBackground()
    print("deleted object: \(objects)")

}

let ifNonExistQuery = PFQuery(className: "Vaccine")
ifNonExistQuery.whereKey("userID", equalTo: self.userID)
ifNonExistQuery.whereKey("vaccineType", equalTo: self.vaccineDocument)
ifNonExistQuery.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

    postImage.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

            print("Saved new object \(postImage)")
            print("Saved new object:\(self.expirationField.text)")

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

            self.expirationField.text = ""
            self.imageToPost.image = UIImage(named: "addDocument.jpg")

    }
}
```

This does the work I want it to only I couldn't get the alertController to work for the delete case.